Deno - Importing "https://deno.land/std@x/" throws "Module not found"
Basically the title.
I've been moving an existing fresh project into a WSL folder, and coming face to face with constant problems.
I've started going bare-bones and starting by just setting up the project by hand.
First problem, Importing the module for fresh, in an import map,
{
  "imports": {
     "$std/": "https://deno.land/std@0.260.0/"
  }
}

throws "Module not found"
So I tried caching directly using deno cache https://deno.land/std@0.216.0/
Same thing, error: Module not found "https://deno.land/std@0.216.0/"
Starting to get super frustrated with deno on Ubuntu/WSL, thinking it might be more effort than it's worth.

Every other version of STD ive tried has also thrown the same error.

deno 1.43.6 (release, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
v8 12.4.254.13
typescript 5.4.5

Well, something interesting happened. I just ran the update script for fresh, it just ignores the import map and downloads some version of std in the background and does not throw.
Not really sure wtf is happening there.

Can you edit the question to include a [mre]?

Are you running from the root folder of the project? I've gotten this error when accessing the project from the parent directory.
